# How to handle img onerror event in Angular 1.5 component

Tags: angularjs

Below code is for angular 1.X only

```
ctrl.onError = function () {
....
}




<div ng-show="$ctrl.isInit">
     <img ng-src="{{$ctrl.url}} onerror="{{$ctrl.onError()}}"></img>
</div>
```

I'd like to handle the onerror event, but it won't work. How to correctly attach onerror event handler?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a simple directive like

(I use it for loader purpose)

```
function myLoader() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link(scope, element) {

      element.on('load', () => {

      });
      element.on('error', () => {

      });
    }
  };
}
```

USAGE

```
<img
      ng-src="{{$ctrl.filename}}"
      alt="{{$ctrl.current.filename}}"
      my-loader/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I need a component to handle it.

Comment: You may be able to adapt [this](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3429-tracking-image-error-events-using-event-delegation-in-javascript.htm) to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have exactly one img in component, you can:

```
$element.find('img').bind('error', () => {
   // handle...
   $scope.$apply();
})
```

Or you can use directive as suggested and pass there you component callback:

```
// directive myError
function myLoader($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('error', () => {
        $parse(attrs.myError)(scope);
      });
    }
  };
}
<img my-error="$ctrl.onError()"></img>
```